# Respuesta a tkMessageBox

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

Este es parte de un una aplicación con registro de sqlite3, pero este no es el tema.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hacer una decisión para hacer o no el registro?

```
def delete(self):
   tkMessageBox.askyesno("Deleting", "Are you sure you want to delete this register?")
```

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de `tkMessageBox.askyesno` es `True` o `False` dependiendo que opción eligio.

```
def delete(self):
    consulta = tkMessageBox.askyesno("Deleting",
                                    "Are you sure you want to delete this register?")
    if consulta:
        #Apreto si, entonces hacer algo.
```

Saludos.